# JPA newbie - Container managed persistence using Websphere and OpenJPA

Tags: jpa, cmp, container-managed

I want to implement Container Managed persistence using Websphere and OpenJPA.

Can anyone provide some insights ?

Is there a way to achieve this without using EJB3 or Spring ?

Answer (score 0):

EJBs and Spring (along with some other Dependency Injection frameworks like Google Guice) implement the Container Managed EntityManager.  If you don't want to use the technology that provides the hooks for the container to handle the transactions and entity managers for you, then you would have to roll your own which is the application managed route.